# How to change language/region and speech in Windows 10 with Powershell script

Tags: powershell, windows-10, environment-variables, cortana

I'm trying to switch language, region and speech inside Windows 10 with a Powershell script. After the script ends, the user will be logged out and have to log in again. So everything should be changed.

But the region and speech is currently not changed. Does anyone know what i'm missing in the script?

```
Set-Culture en-US
Set-WinSystemLocale -SystemLocale en-US
Set-WinUILanguageOverride -Language en-US
Set-WinUserLanguageList en-US -Force
logoff;exit
```

I want that the user to just start the poweshell script so he can use Cortana with a different speech.

Would be very happy if someone could help me or give some further hints.

Greeting
Christian

Comment: Have a look on this thread: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6a21b20a-4d04-460a-b672-968de78c6646/command-line-tools-to-completely-change-regioninput-language-for-default-user-and-welcome-screen?forum=winservergen

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the solution. Thanks for the link to the thread.

To switch on german language

```
Set-Culture de-DE
Set-WinSystemLocale -SystemLocale de-DE
Set-WinUILanguageOverride -Language de-DE
Set-WinUserLanguageList de-DE -Force
Set-WinHomeLocation -GeoId 94
shutdown -r;exit
```

For en-US use following lines

```
Set-Culture en-US
Set-WinSystemLocale -SystemLocale en-US
Set-WinUILanguageOverride -Language en-US
Set-WinUserLanguageList en-US -Force
Set-WinHomeLocation -GeoId 244
shutdown -r;exit
```

After the restart, a second manual restart is necessary.

Greetings 
Christian