# How can I force app language in Microsoft Teams for all users? GPO? Script?

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have deployed a PowerApp canvas app to our org in Teams, and it has dates in it. The dates format in the app match whatever the language of the Microsoft Teams desktop client is. This is sub-optimal, and what we are trying to fix. The Microsoft Teams desktop client defaults to English US, and we want to change that to English Ireland for all users (for this and other reasons). We have 7k+ users, and I would rather programmatically set this language globally, rather than asking each individual user to set their own language locally.

I have tried modifying the desktop-settings.json file by setting "currentWebLanguage":"en-ie" but the dates in the app do not show correctly, and it looks like the Teams client is still starting in whatever the previous language was. I do not know where this setting is coming from.

Here is an example of what I have done to test this:

1. Check language in Teams client = En US
2. Close Teams client
3. Set "currentWebLanguage":"en-ie" in "desktop-settings.json"
4. Open Teams client
5. Check Language, but it is still En US in Teams client, and app displays wrong date formats
6. Check desktop-settings.json, it is still showing "currentWebLanguage":"en-ie" despite the Teams desktop client showing En US

So, how can I set the actual app language in the Teams desktop client so that the dates in my app will show up correctly? There are virtually no GPO settings, and the policies in the Teams Admin centre do not cover this.

To be clear, I understand that dates can be forced into a language format in PowerApps, but this is not a suitable response to the need, for a variety of reasons. The goal is to change the App Language in the MS Teams client.

I appreciate any and all suggestions, thank you

Comment: At this moment, there is no different way to change the date/format without changing the app language.https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-settings-in-teams-b506e8f1-1a96-4cf1-8c6b-b6ed4f424bc7

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT That's what I am trying to accomplish. How do I administratively change the app language of MS Teams for all users?

Comment: Changing the language administratively for entire tenant/organization doesn't seem to be feasible.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I don't need to change it for the tenant if there is some way to change it at the client level. Is there a PowerShell script I can run against users' desktops to change the language setting? Is it stored in the registry, for example?

Comment: Please refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51183960/how-to-change-language-region-and-speech-in-windows-10-with-powershell-script) which explains how to change language/region of your system using PowerShell script.