# How to change the regional time format programmatically in windows 10

Tags: c++, windows

We are trying to change the regional time format in windows 10 using code. When we are using intl.cpl command with the xml, it is updating for current user and it is not retained once we log out of the system and log in. But when we use the windows UI we are able to retain the value and this is working perfectly.
[image]

We need to do it programmatically.

We have used the below xml.

```
<gs:GlobalizationServices xmlns:gs="urn:longhornGlobalizationUnattend">
<gs:UserList><gs:User UserID="Current" CopySettingsToDefaultUserAcct="true" CopySettingsToSystemAcct="true"/>
</gs:UserList>
<gs:UserLocale><gs:Locale Name="en-GB" SetAsCurrent="true" ResetAllSettings="false"/></gs:UserLocale>
</gs:GlobalizationServices>
```

Also We have used the powersell command prompt as suggested here  [How to change language/region and speech in Windows 10 with Powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51183960/how-to-change-language-region-and-speech-in-windows-10-with-powershell-script)

Comment: Are you mixing C# and C++?  Not recommended, I suggest picking one or the other.  For example, C# has garbage collection and marshalling and has easy connection to the ".Net" universe.  The C++ language has easy access to pointers and references.  Transferring between the is possible, but difficult.

Comment: we followed this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/automate-regional-language-settings).
It works in some systems but in some systems after restart it reverts back.
Do you know any group policy or local security policy restricting this ?